# Is there something like bower list --path for npm?

Tags: list, npm, bower

I'm new to npm and really like the idea of managing packages via json. But i'm not quite sure how to use the installed front-end packages. If I install something like admin-lte I get jQuery Versions and Plugins and stuff, but how do I refer to them the in the correct way in my HTML?

What if admin-lte uses different Versions from Bootstrap than I want to use?

What I saw in Bower is that with

```
bower list --path
```

I get a list of all the main files to use in a frontend project. So is there an equivalent in npm?